# Pass all parameters as array PHP mysqli query?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I want to pass all parameters in array rather then pass them one by one .

My Query:

```
Select col_1,col_2,col_3,col_4 FROM table WHERE col_1=?i AND col_2 =?s AND col_3=?i AND col_4=?s;

$list = $db_con->getAll($sql, 12,'string',18,'name'); //Currently I've passed
```

Is it possible to pass like following ?

```
$list = $db_con->getAll($sql, array(12,'string',18,'name')); //Want to do
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace the `OR` clauses by `IN`. It would be easy to handle then.

Comment: No its not about single column , its about multiple parameters

Comment: Can we get the code of getAll? You should also rewrite your question, people don't seem to understand what you're actually asking.

Comment: It's a function of SAFe_MySQL lib

Comment: Would be easy with PDO: `$stmt->execute($array)`

Answer (score 1):

As of PHP 5.6 you can use a [splat operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.new-features.php#migration56.new-features.splat):

```
$args = array(12,'string',18,'name');
$list = $db_con->getAll($sql, ...$args);
```

If your PHP version is not recent, then `call_user_func_array()` can be used this way:

```
$sql = "Select col_1,col_2,col_3,col_4 FROM tabele WHERE col_1=?i AND col_2 =?s AND col_3=?i AND col_4=?s";
$args = array(12,'string',18,'name');
array_unshift($args, $sql);
$list = call_user_func_array(array($db_con, 'getAll'), $args);
```

but as you can see the first version is way better, not to mention that all PHP versions below 5.6 are already outdated - so I'd strongly encourage  you to upgrade instead.

Answer (score -2):

You can write this

```
Select col_1,col_2,col_4 FROM tabele WHERE (col_1=?i or col_1 =?i) IN (col_2=?i or col_2 =?i);

$list = $db_con->getAll($sql, 1,2,1,2); //Currently I've passed

$list = $db_con->getAll($sql, array(1,2,1,2)); //Want to do
```

Comment: Need to pass multiple parameters not multiple values